# Git: Don't call post-receive hook when deleting a branch

Tags: git

We are using a post-receive hook in Git to deploy a PHP "app". The script (Bash) checks the branch name and do a rsync on the correct server based on a prefix in the branch name.

This work pretty well, except for one thing: it tries to do a deployment when we delete a branch.

I checked at many places, and I didn't find a way to find out from the script if the operation is a delete.

Is there a way to achieve this. The script is on a bare repository (managed by Gitolite), it is not on the developers workstation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When git receives a push, the `post-receive` hook is invoked and passed data on stdin about each ref that was delivered, in rows of `<old-sha> <new-sha> <ref-name>`, like so:

```
e1f5c274e296f1c5148161f9d4e5eb43a6743e54 1eea3f51cf926c3710f8fa4a06f503041c4597f0 refs/heads/master
```

When a branch is deleted, the `<new-sha>` entry is all zeros, like so:

```
6b239c481453c7fc2513b02e8aa0cd9c1ffa25cb 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 refs/heads/foo
```

So, you can adjust your `post-receive` hook to detect this (and prevent this branch from triggering a deployment) using logic like:

```
#!/bin/sh -

while read OLDSHA NEWSHA REF ; do
  if [ "$NEWSHA" = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000" ]; then
    # This ref has been deleted! Respond appropriately.
  fi
done
```

Remember that a single push can contain update multiple branches, too! You'll probably want to accumulate a set of branches that should be deployed, that begin with the appropriate prefix and have a nonzero `NEWSHA`.